ターミナルソフトRloginでSSHキーを作成することはできますか？
ターミナルソフトRloginでSSHキーを作成することはできますか？
「認証キーを作成」の意味は？

困っていること
パスフレーズ入力を求められ、入力するとエラーになる。
バージョン
2.29.9(2024/10/25)

2024/11/19 追記しました。
環境
・Windows 10 Home 22H2 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600
・Rlogin 64bit版 2.20.3バージョン
・Rlogin 64bit版 2.22.9バージョン
エラー発生状況
「作成時に設定したパスフレーズを入力してください」と表示され、パスフレーズを入力するも、そこから先へ進めませんでした。
肝心のエラーメッセージは覚えていません。
質問時点の意図
エラーを解消したいが、そもそも「RloginでSSHキーを作成できるか」知りたく質問しました。
現在の疑問点
このエラーメッセージはどういうときに表示されるか？
パスフレーズの一致はどうやって確認しているか。(パスフレーズはどこへ保存されているか)
サーバーへの公開鍵の登録有無は関係するか。
その他現状
※SSHキーは、その後Windowsで作成したので、困っている状態ではありません

参考: 「RLogin」でSSH用の秘密鍵と公開鍵のペアを作成する方法 / アプリのバージョンも確認してください。 https://github.com/kmiya-culti/RLogin/releases/

あなたが聞くべきなのは「作成できるかどうか？」ではなく「エラーを解消するにはどうすればいいか？」ではないのですか？やりたいことに対して質問の題名がちぐはぐです。エラーを解消したいのであれば、「表示されるエラーメッセージ」「バージョン」「64bit版か32bit版か」「OSのバージョンとアーキテクチャ(例: Win11 Pro 24H2 Arm64)」を追記してください。

本文に追記しました。

RLogin v2.29.9 で試しましたが「認証キーの作成」は特に問題はありませんでした。
申し訳ないですが、そもそも自分が何をしているのかを把握できていない気がします。

質問に貼られているキャプチャには "centos..." というエントリが表示されているので、 鍵の作成自体はできているはずです。

「作成時に設定したパスフレーズを入力してください」というメッセージは、少なくとも 鍵作成時に表示されるエラーではありません (後述)

パスフレーズは公開鍵と秘密鍵の作成時、任意で設定可能なフレーズですが、人間が読める形では保存されません。



RLogin で表示されたという「作成時に設定したパスフレーズを入力してください」については、認証キーをファイルにエクスポートしようとした時に (入力が間違っていた場合に) 表示されました。
作成時のパスフレーズを思い出すか、新しく作り直してください。
なお、パスフレーズは "空" の状態でも作成可能です。もちろん設定しておいた方がより安全ですが、利用環境に応じてご自身で判断してください。
参考:
「よく分かる公開鍵認証」～初心者でもよくわかる！VPSによるWebサーバー運用講座(2)

質問時の状況としては、作成後、実際に使用する際、作成時の「パスフレーズ」を入力しても弾かれたので、作成自体がうまくいっていないのではないか、と思い質問しました。とりあえず、RLogin で「認証キーの作成」ができることは分かりました。試していただきありがとうございました


ターミナルソフトRloginでSSHキーを作成することはできますか？

こちらをどうぞ
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Rlogin%E3%81%A7SSH%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90
